# Executing .net apps from console in windows 10 doesn't work

Tags: .net, console-application, windows-10

I have Windows 10 (with november update). I have Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise edition too. 
I have donwloaded a couple of solutions from github [Wyam] and [misakai-baker].
When I open the solutions, build and execute a debug, everything seems to be working fine. I can execute the apps and step into the code and so on.
Problems happen when I go to the debug folder with a console (even with admin rights) and type the name of the program. 
The program will simply not execute.
I created a hello world console app and built it. It has the same behavior.
What is weird is that I have the same trouble both in my Surface tablet and in my Workstation.

In this [Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kHXQ.gif) you will see what I mean by the application won't execute. The cursor just stays in there.

[image: Image here]

I have discovered too that the console application will work if I turn on my workstation without plug-in it to the network. Once I plug-in it to the network, the behavior reproduces.

Have you ever had this problem before? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: same issue with console "cmd" ?

Comment: I see you starting wyam.exe but I don't see it in the folder, do you have that exe as part of your PATH variable?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain yes I have it in the path

Comment: @dacrovinunghi both cmd and PowerShell have the same problem

Comment: and with "execute" or start ?

Comment: @dacrovinunghi execute is not recognized as a command in my cmd. With start I have the same behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out what the problem was. It turns out that the problem was Avast antivirus. I uninstalled it and the application executes normally.

Comment: Crazy! Glad you worked through that - I'll keep it in mind in case anyone else has a similar problem.

Comment: You can just disable avast for a while also. If you need it to 'let go' of a file, then you'll need to stop the service all together. Then boom, your file starts working.